# Is it possible to project an image into the eye which appears to be on a focal plane above source, and is larger?

Tags: optics, hologram

Is it possible to project an image into the eye, without wearing glasses or using a projection screen, which:

1. Appears to be on a focal plane *in front of* rather than behind the source
2. Appears larger in width/height than the source

The image doesn't need to be truly volumetric, appear when viewing from the side, appear to anyone other than the user, or display true black. Less ambitious than R2D2 :) Goal: take a smartphone-size device out of my pocket, put it on a cafe table, look down and see a floating image larger than the device.

Side view (image only visible to eye, not visible to person to the side): https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9M6k.jpg

Example: smartphone with pseudo 3D using eye tracking and parallax:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXRHuaO38bs&t=3m40s

Comment: Top down view: http://imgur.com/a/ASwfB


Example 2: auto HUD where virtual image appears behind windshield: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wkf_WEek8bc&t=1m17s

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if the display was a laser scanner that projected straight into your eye. It would be classed as a [Virtual Retinal Display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_retinal_display)